# How to create aliases in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create `aliases` in laravel like `Auth` so that i can use it in view just like

`Auth::user()`.

For example, i want to return data from my setting table and want to use it like

`Setting::method()->value`. in view and `use Setting` in controllers.

What should i create for this `Facades` Or `Service Providers`? Provide me some procedures.
I tried using `Service Providers` but i am confused how to call database there.

Comment: Why do you want to modify the authorization model in the first place?

Comment: i do not want to modify it .I want to create something just like Auth aliases .
So that i can use it in view using Setting::method()->value
Or in controller using 
use Setting;
Just like auth.

Comment: You can create static method into your model and call into view, let me know if need more detail

Comment: You don't call models directly from view. That breaks the MVC general idea. You gather data in the controller and pass the prepared variable to the view.

Comment: `config/app.php` has an `aliases` section

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will be a long answer, using Laravel 5.4.

1. You need a service class (in this case, it's a concrete class behind the facade). I made it inside `app/Services` folder:

---

```
namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;

class Setting
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(DatabaseManager $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function method()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

As you see, I inject the database inside that concrete class. This is the magic of Laravel IoC. It will automatically resolve any dependency into your concrete class.

2. Next, create a facade. I made it inside `app/Facades` folder:

---

```
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Setting extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'setting';
    }
}
```

Notice the `setting` string returned from `getFacadeAccessor`. You need to register this service name later to the Container (IoC). The magic behind this facade is, it's automatically call (proxy) any static method to the instance method of concrete class, in this case you can call:

```
Service::method()
```

3. Register the service to the container. Inside your `AppServiceProvider`

---

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\Setting;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // ...

        $this->app->singleton(Setting::class);
        $this->app->alias(Setting::class, 'setting');
    }
}
```

In this Service Provider, I declare that `Setting` service is a singleton service. Which means, you can use `Setting` service in another place without re-initialize class, in another words you are using the same instance across file. Last, I tell the container that `Setting` service has another alias, name `setting`, so Container can figure out which Concrete Class behind `App/Facade/Setting`.

4. For aliasing, as mentioned by apokryfos. Register your facade alias inside `config/app.php`, find the section `aliases` and add this line:

---

```
'aliases' => [

    // ...

    'Setting' => App\Facades\Setting::class,

],
```

After this you can call your facade like this:

```
use Setting;

Setting::method();
```

Hope this helps.